# How to segregate common libraries from different war files into common location?

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, shared-libraries, war, ear

This might seem a novice question but just want to clarify. I have a project which has multiple wars deployed on server. Most of these use same jar files in lib folder. Is there a way I can segregate common libraries (say build an EAR/lib) from where they can read rather than packaging same jars with individual wars.

Comment: You can put those jars in tomcat/lib,or jboss/server/default/lib.

Comment: Are you certain they're the same jars? Problem is different wars might be using different versions of common jars... By design a servlet container will ensure each set of files is loaded onto a different classpath.

Comment: @Bala Can't be done. Since when I am building them, build.xml reads lib from war<name>/web/lib. And as a result after built, they all just get packaged along.

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Yes they're same jars. Most of them use gwt jars from same gwt installation directly. So version conflict can't be there since all of them are standard ones. Something like this..

Project 1
    compile - gwt jars in classpath
    build war - gwt jars in war<name>/.../lib/
Project 2....
Project 3...
Eventually, on the server ..
deploy/.../war1(gwt jars), war2(gwt jars), war3(gwt jars), war4(gwt jars)....

Comment: @nix_stack, you should not include those jars while packing. I don't much about ant but using maven, you can specify jar as container provided, then it will not be included in your war.

Comment: Ok your answer to @Bala contains the problem. When building the code you're referencing jars containers in a deployment of your application. As stated if you were using Maven you could declare your dependency as "provided" scope and it would be downloaded, made available for compilation but not packaged with the war. Your ANT build needs to do something similar. Either embrace a dependency management solution like ivy, or else store your dependencies with your code, but ensure they are grouped by dependency type: "compile", "runtime", "test", "provided"